# Get_option() in JavaScript error?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

When i star my page i receive this error in firebug: "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal".
It is my code:

```
$('.survey_title').html('<?php 
                    $found1 = get_option("heading");
                    if($found1)
                    {
                        echo  $found1 ;

                    }
                ?>').css('color', 'red');
```

Where is the problem???

Comment: Read the generated source and you will be enlightened.

Comment: For one thing, you can't call PHP from javascript like that - PHP is evaluated serverside, and the results sent to the browser long before javascript will run.

Comment: @andrewsi, You can use PHP to generate JavaScript...

Comment: @Brad - From the snippet here, I'm unsure if he's using PHP to generate javascript, or using javascript to run PHP.

Comment: Definitely looks like JS trying to run PHP

Comment: I want to display this option in...html('');

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, you need to use a backslash `\` before a new line in a string literal.

What you should be doing is using `json_encode()` around any value from PHP to JavaScript to let it fix the escaping for you.  Better yet, to assign it to a variable before your JS to make it easier to read.

```
var titleHTML = <?php echo json_encode($found1); ?>;
$('.survey_title').html(titleHTML).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: @user2417332, No problem.  Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If my answer was useful, click the check mark next to it.  This gives points to the person answering, and brings the answer to the top for when people come to this question later on.  You can read more about it on the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq